# Very short pulses and BJT Transistor SOA

Tags: transistors, datasheet

Say I have a transistor as shown below, MJL4281A. It is rated for 15Amps, but the SOA shows that 30Amps can be safe in short 10 ms pulses.

I will not exceed 30 amps, however; I intend to use it for much shorter duration pulses. For ~10us of a 100uS pulse I will be marginally outside the 10ms line, about where the "T" in "Thermal" is on the chart.

Some data-sheets list a pulse thermal resistance. This one does not, so I cannot make my own thermal limit calculations. Should I discard the transistor and move on?

[image]

Comment: Will you really have 60V across the transistor at that point? Or do you have a 60V supply but most of the voltage is across the load, not the transistor?

Comment: As Spehro says, it will probably work fine for 100µs.

However at 30A its hFe will be very low, so the driver which will be a smaller transistor, risks running out of SOA instead of the main transistor.

Why not use a MOSFET?

Comment: @bobflux, excellent point. Will have to look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the SOA for shorter pulses does not increase the maximum current but increases the limits at higher Vce. Curve from [here](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/mosfet_igbt/igbt-008.html)

[image]

So I suspect you're more than okay. This (obsolete) transistor is designed for audio so it's not characterized at very short pulse widths. Of course if it's a high reliability application or there is possibility of damage you may want an actual datasheet SOA curve to CYA.